# Data recovery from a formated usb drive

Tags: usb, data-recovery, keepass, mft

I recently made a stupid mistake, instead of changing my .kdbx file on google drive, I changed one I had on USB drive with the same name.

The USB drive was later formatted and used as windows installation media.

Do you think there is anyway of recovering the kdbx file?

I've tried using GetDataBack Pro which shows me MFT entries possibly of the previous state, as well as some transaction logs and a invalid bitmap file.

Comment: If GetDataBack (I have used it) cannot get the data from the USB drive, you probably do not have much chance to recover it.

Comment: Your chances of recovery are inversely proportional to the percentage of data written by the installer compared to the overall data size of the drive. On an 8GB stick your chances are already more than 50% that **all** of the file was overwritten. I wouldn't like to guess at the chances that any single  part of it had been.

Comment: It was a 64gig usb but i think the file is gone as the file was written to the usb when it was pretty much empty and was probably overwritten by the windows installer

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare an individual fingerprint file for Photorec.
As there are different version of those file around you might need some fingerprint files.

https://gist.github.com/lgg/e6ccc6e212d18dd2ecd8a8c116fb1e45

Comment: Why wouldn’t you have just provided the information in your answer?